# DateTime format Regular expression YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

Can someone write a regular expression to test this date format `2012/11/14 14:28:12`?

I already have a regular expression for the date part:

```
/^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}$/
```

How can I add to this to test for the presence of a time?

Comment: `/^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/`

Comment: Are you sure that `9999/99/99 99:99:99` is the correct date?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143070/javascript-regex-iso-datetime

Answer (score 5):

I‘d use the `Date` constructor instead to test a date in that format:

```
var isValid = !!new Date('2012/11/14 14:28:12').getTime();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rwCeA/

Works in all my test browsers (safari/chrome/firefox/ie7+). The Date constructor takes many date variants, but you can combine this with a regexp to force a certain format.

Answer (score 4):

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/Db3JM/ I wrote recently is a more sophisticated piece of code, the relevant regular expression is :

```
/(?:(\d{4})([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\2([0-3]?\d)|([0-3]?\d)([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\6(\d{4}))(?:\s+([012]?\d)([:hap])([0-5]\d))?/i
```